# Need assistance on understanding how to solve Plesk Login Error "Zend_Db_Adapter_Exception"

Tags: cpanel, plesk

we have a Plesk panel from where we host all of our official websites, recently it ran into some problem and showed this error on the Plesk login page:

```
Server Error
500
Zend_Db_Adapter_Exception
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory

Type    Zend_Db_Adapter_Exception
Message SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory
File    Abstract.php
Line    144
```

After searching a bit came to know that Plesk support has provided a solution for it at:
[Plesk support solution](https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000254773-Plesk-inaccessible-ERROR-Zend-Db-Adapter-Exception-SQLSTATE-HY000-2002-Connection-refused)

As per the solution, I did install putty, and using my IP and password I went to step #1.
But I can't understand how to do steps #2 and #3 as I have no experience in this stuff.

**Steps from the Plesk support:**

**Step #1:** Connect to the server via SSH.

**Step #2:** Create the configuration file with necessary content:

For Debian/Ubuntu:

```
echo "d /var/run/mysqld 0755 mysql mysql -" >> /etc/tmpfiles.d/mysql.conf
```

For CentOS/RHEL/CloudLinux:

```
echo "d /var/run/mariadb 0755 mysql mysql -" >> /etc/tmpfiles.d/mysql.conf
```

**Step #3:** Reboot the server

All my files I have worked on in all the websites database are still there, please help me understand on fixing this just for once, will take a backup of all files and think permanent solution.

Just once, please.

Answer (score 0):

If you connected to the server via SSH using PuTTY in the console you should see something like this:

```
[root@server:~]#
```

In order to find what operation system you are using type:

```
plesk -v
```

From the output besides Plesk version and other information you should find what OS you are using, most likely it will be CentOS, Ubuntu or Debian. Regarding this information copy and paste command provided by Plesk.

After this just reboot your server with command:

```
reboot
```

However I would recommend to contact your server provider for assistance as executing tasks as root via SSH can be very risky if you have non or very little experience with systems administration.